# Filter dropdown boxes to show which options are selected

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, filter

I have a few dropdown filters on my site that filter the data on 'submit'. You can see these dropdowns here - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgsAZ.png).I would like it to tell me which filters are selected, using a 'x' cross method, so that customers can un-select the option for that filter, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vacT.png).

Can anyone suggest a way that I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site is more for help with the actual code. I would suggect looking in to Javascript to acheive this. How you then send it to the server is up to you.

Comment: I was just looking for suggestions on where to look and what to look for really? I have Googled, but searching for 'filter cross' etc doesn't give me a lot. I was hoping someone could give me the name of this method of filtering at least..

Comment: This interface is custom, you can just do it with Javascript. A similar componenet called `select2` exsists which you [can look at the code for](https://select2.github.io/). It will not do the filtering though, that it between the frontend and the backend. Your PHP needs to filter from the database.

Comment: Thanks Joe - much appreciated! I will take a look!